# Android how to run thread for each 25 ms?

Tags: android, timertask, android-handler

I try to run threads one after the other. The delay between them must be fixed to 25 ms.  Do you have any suggestions? Is it possible to update Android so frequently?

I have tried `handler.post` and call `handler.post` inside the thread. But it didn't work. After that, I have tried `timer.schedule`. Although timer.schedule works well, it does not always return the exact time.

```
long startTime,delay,nextThread =25;
...
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        /*
            do something and show on UI;
        */
        delay = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
             if(delay<0)
                 delay=0;
             nextThread = 25 - delay;
             if (nextThread<0)
                 nextThread=0;
    }
},0,nextThread);
```

As I said before timer returns generally on time but sometimes it returns late.

Comment: How long does the "do something" task take? If it could be more than 25ms then this exhibit this behaviour.  Also posting a runnable to UI thread doesn't guarantee immediate execution.  Maybe some logging to confirm where the inaccuracy actually lies, the Timer task, the algorithm execution time or the runnable posting to UI thread.

Comment: "do something" part takes almost 10ms. I calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(/* Your Runnable */, 0, 25, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Or RxJava:

```
Flowable.interval(0, 25, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribe(/* Code to execute */);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It seems the code runs as I wanted but I need to do more tests to be sure. If it passes all tests, I will accept your post as answer. Thank you again.